# Store the session on a click and refresh page to display content

Tags: php, session

I am trying to implement session one on 1 page (get.php?id=1) (that page should be included in index to display image) which has image inside that file with text "get file" as example. I need after user click on that image or link page should be refreshed and content should be displayed (video as example) on index.php without that get.php page, only content

i have tried to add session on page 1 and get session on the index page but i need the function when user only click on the image. I couldnt find any code which can help me do this

I will try to explain like this I am on index.php > session is not set so get.php?id=3 is displayed (that file includes image which says only to click on it) > user click on it > page refresh and video is displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript to post the click event to index.php:

```
<img src="get.php?id=1" id="click_img"/>
<form method="post" id="clickForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="click_event" value="1" />
</form>

<script>
    $('#click_img').click(function() {
        $('#clickForm').submit()
    })
</script>
```

index.php add codes:

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['show_video'] = !empty($_SESSION['show_video']) || isset($_POST['click_event']);
```